# R read.csv how to ignore carriage return?

Tags: r, csv, carriage-return, read.table, read.csv

I need to read a text file (tab-separated) that has some carriage returns inside some fields.

If I use read.table, it gives me an error:

```
line 6257 did not have 20 elements
```

If I use read.csv, it doesn't give an error, but creates a new line in that place, putting the next fields in the first fields of the new line.

How can I avoid this? I can't alter the file itself (the script is to be run elsewhere). Also the broken strings don't have quotation marks (no strings in the file have). One option would be to read the carriage return as a single space, or as \n, but how?

Comment: use  the argument `fill=TRUE`

Comment: fill=TRUE will only put blank spaces in the last fields, what is after the carriage return still goes to the next line, messing the data.

Comment: Sorry -- misread the problem..  What do you get with `readLines` ?

Comment: I get an array of strings, not a data.frame.

Comment: That's the point: the full strings are read in and then you can regexp them.

Comment: Yes, it might work. But I managed to change the original files, adding the quotation marks. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use read.table instead of read.csv and set allowEscapes to TRUE.

```
read.table("your/path",sep=",",allowEscapes=TRUE)
```

I tested w/ the following:

1. wrote a csv file in excel

contents of csv file:

```
1,df,3,"4 
"
df,"df
",3,a
```

result:

```
  V1   V2 V3   V4
1  1   df  3 4 \n
2 df df\n  3    a
```

Comment: allowEscapes would make sense if I had a \n in my data. I don't have a \n, I have real carriage returns (ASCII 13).

Comment: I tested read.table and allowEscapes and it worked for actual returns (not \n).  Made an example file using excel w/ line breaks inside the cells, saved as csv.  It read properly with allowEscapes, but not with readcsv.

Comment: OK, I could reproduce your example, but mine still doesn't work. The problem seem to be that my strings are not delimited by quotation marks " ". And I can't edit the original file.

Comment: I see what you are saying.The problem is that if the line break isn't quoted, how can one tell which line breaks represent a jump to the next row and which are just the contents of cells.  If you can come up with a pattern there, then you can write your own function to read in the csv as character and parse it via your own function.

Comment: This is a problem only if the line break is on the last column. But yes, you are right. I think it's better to ask them to quote the files on the server.

Comment: I could change the files, adding the quotation marks. Now allowEscapes isn't even necessary. Thank you.